# com.mashape.unirest.request.BaseRequest.asJson

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mashape

**please help me how to implement Zilyo API of Mashape in android Application.**

i am integrating Zilyo Mashape API in Android Application.but i am getting a some error.

**here is my code.**

```
        try {
            request = Unirest.get("https://zilyo.p.mashape.com/search?isinstantbook=true&nelatitude=22.37&nelongitude=-154.48000000000002&provider=airbnb%2Chousetrip&swlatitude=18.55&swlongitude=-160.52999999999997")
                    .header("X-Mashape-Key", "PtYDw5a2WEmshZZXBZRIFMR9WIxOp1jHYzRjsnOPWqZO7PMRTy")
                    .header("Accept", "application/json")
                    .asJson();
        } catch (UnirestException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**build.gradle**

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'  
compile project(':unirest-java-1.3.21')
```

**LogCat error**

```
06-22 12:24:25.655 12799-19685/com.trs.jupit E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
06-22 12:24:25.655 12799-19685/com.trs.jupit E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
06-22 12:24:25.655 12799-19685/com.trs.jupit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
06-22 12:24:25.655 12799-19685/com.trs.jupit E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
06-22 12:24:25.655 12799-19685/com.trs.jupit E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
06-22 12:24:25.655 12799-19685/com.trs.jupit E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
06-22 12:24:25.655 12799-19685/com.trs.jupit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
06-22 12:24:25.655 12799-19685/com.trs.jupit E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-22 12:24:25.655 12799-19685/com.trs.jupit E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-22 12:24:25.655 12799-19685/com.trs.jupit E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
06-22 12:24:25.655 12799-19685/com.trs.jupit E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig
06-22 12:24:25.655 12799-19685/com.trs.jupit E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.mashape.unirest.http.options.Options.refresh(Options.java:45)
06-22 12:24:25.655 12799-19685/com.trs.jupit E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.mashape.unirest.http.options.Options.<clinit>(Options.java:34)
06-22 12:24:25.655 12799-19685/com.trs.jupit E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpClientHelper.prepareRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:154)
06-22 12:24:25.655 12799-19685/com.trs.jupit E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpClientHelper.request(HttpClientHelper.java:131)
06-22 12:24:25.655 12799-19685/com.trs.jupit E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.mashape.unirest.request.BaseRequest.asJson(BaseRequest.java:68)
06-22 12:24:25.655 12799-19685/com.trs.jupit E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.trs.jupit.Stay$DownloadJSON.doInBackground(Stay.java:163)
06-22 12:24:25.655 12799-19685/com.trs.jupit E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.trs.jupit.Stay$DownloadJSON.doInBackground(Stay.java:152)
06-22 12:24:25.655 12799-19685/com.trs.jupit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-22 12:24:25.655 12799-19685/com.trs.jupit E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-22 12:24:25.655 12799-19685/com.trs.jupit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230) 
06-22 12:24:25.655 12799-19685/com.trs.jupit E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080) 
06-22 12:24:25.655 12799-19685/com.trs.jupit E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573) 
06-22 12:24:25.655 12799-19685/com.trs.jupit E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: Search for Lollipop and apache http client removal

Comment: @EugenMartynov same problem occur

Comment: What did you do after search?

Comment: i am searching apache http client removal in android and use this library useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

Comment: i resolve this problem . simply use the  HTTPPOST method  and add header then you can get JSON